# ngFor doesn't read the array if I write it on the .ts file

Tags: angular, ngfor

This is the moment I call the ngFor directive in my search-page.component.html :

```
<mat-select #orarioForm placeholder="A che ora vuoi prenotare?">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let hour of availableHours">{{hour}}:00</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This is the declaration of the array in search-page.component.ts :

```
export class SearchPageComponent implements OnInit {
    ... /* variables declaration*/

    availableHours: ['08' , '09' , '10' , '11' , '12' , '13' , '14' , '15' , '16' , '17' , '18' , '19' , '20' , '21' , '22' , '23'];

    ... /* constructor and methods
}
```

ngFor works only if I explicitly write my array inside the directive, like this:

```
<mat-select #orarioForm placeholder="A che ora vuoi prenotare?">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let hour of ['08' , '09' , '10' , '11' , '12' , '13' , '14' , '15' , '16' , '17' , '18' , '19' , '20' , '21' , '22' , '23']">{{hour}}:00</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But this is not the way I want it to work.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: I'm sure that is becuase you are using : instead of =. Consider install in your code editor some type of linter.

Comment: The fun fact is that I use tslint, but it didn't mark that line as an error. Thank anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the values with **`=`**,

```
  availableHours  = ['08' , '09' , '10' , '11' , '12' , '13' , '14' , '15' , '16' , '17' , '18' , '19' , '20' , '21' , '22' , '23'];
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes the solution is so trivial that you can spend hours without finding it...

Answer (score 0):

: its for typing,
= Its for the assing